# Why not use "include_directories" in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I've read and watched some videos about CMake, and everyone recommend not to use `include_directories`, and instead use `target_include_directories`. But I didn't understand what is the real reason behind this recommendation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 main reasons

- Limiting the scope of include directories to only those targets that need them
- Allow for modifications of one target without requiring an update of the cmake logic for other projects
- Allow for easier reuse of a project as part of a larger project

### Limiting the scope of include dirs

The goal is to reduce the visibility of include directories to a minimum. If you use `add_subdirectory` after doing `include_directories`, all the targets created from the subdir or descendants of the subdir see the include directory added with `include_directories`.

**subdir/CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_library(subdir_lib ...)
...
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_subdirectory(subdir)
...
include_directories(some_include_dir)
```

vs

```
include_directories(some_include_dir)
...
add_subdirectory(subdir)
```

The difference between the 2 `CMakeLists.txt` files may be difficult to see, especially if there are is a lot of logic between the 2 commands; this makes this kind of logic hard to maintain.

### "Inheritance"/Ease of recombination

Using `target_include_directories` also makes it easier to provide targets that link a library with the include dirs required. Include directories added via `include_directories` are not available to linking targets automatically, but with `target_include_directories(... PUBLIC ...)` this is quite easy to achieve. `include_directories` won't work on targets created from directories that are not created in subdirectories containing the command.

#### Example project

- Library `A`
- Library `B` requires library `A`; the public headers of `B` use public includes from `A`
- Library `C` does not use `A` or `B`

File system:

```
.
|---A
|   |---include
|   |      |---- A
|   |            |---- a.hpp
|   |
|   |--- a.cpp
|
|---B
|   |---include
|   |      |---- B
|   |            |---- b.hpp
|   |
|   |--- b.cpp
|
|---C
|   |---include
|   |      |---- C
|   |            |---- c.hpp
|   |
|   |--- c.cpp
|
|---CMakeLists.txt
```

Now you need to give `B`, but not `C` access to the headers of `A`. Using `target_link_libraries` this is trivial, but with `include_directories` you'd need to be careful about the order of `add_subdirectory`s in `CMakeLists.txt`

**CMakeList.txt**

```
add_subdirectory(A)
add_subdirectory(B)
add_subdirectory(C)
```

**A/CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_library(A ...)
target_include_directories(A PUBLIC include)
```

**B/CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_library(B ...)
target_include_directories(B PUBLIC include)
target_link_libraries(B PUBLIC A) # quite simple to provide access to A's include dir to linking libs using PUBLIC here, if required
```

**C/CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_library(C ...)
target_include_directories(C PUBLIC include)
```

Now let's assume you want to rename the directory `A` to `AB`. All you need to do is rename the dir on the file system and replace `add_subdirectory(A)` with `add_subdirectory(AB)` in `CMakeLists.txt`.

Alternatively assume you want to use libraries `B` and `C` as part of a larger project: All you need to do, if you use `target_include_directories` instead of `include_directories`, is add the directory containing the toplevel `CMakeLists.txt` using `add_subdirectory` and all you need to do is use `target_link_libraries(NewTarget PRIVATE B C)` to gain access to all the required include directories instead of doing

```
add_subdirectory(OriginalProject)

include_directories(OriginalProject/B/include)
include_directories(OriginalProject/C/include)
include_directories(OriginalProject/A/include) # did you remember this one is needed by B?

add_executable(NewTarget ...)
```